# Why need characteristic matrix positive so that from 1 difference in input state spreads to all other differences in output state after R rounds?

Tags: block-cipher, differential-analysis, spn

I read the paper "Provable Security Evaluation of Structures against Impossible Differential and Zero Correlation Linear Cryptanalysis" - author: Bing Sun. In this paper proof of theorem 2 mentioned that from 1 difference in input state spreads to all other differences in other state after R_1(P) round, where R_1(P) is the 1 type primitive index of P.

P is the matrix representing the linear layer in struct SPN. R_1(P) = (P*)^t. Minimum t to (P*)^t=1 is type 1 primitive index of P, where P* is characteristic matrix of P.

Can explain it to me? Thanks.

Comment: Quesstion unclear. Please also make the effort to format the question/equations properly and clarify. don't use strange SMS type abbreviations. For formatting equations using mathjax see https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171/using-mathjax-tex-on-the-cryptography-site/1070#1070